# Concurrency: Frontend, Middleware and Backend

Tags: web, concurrency, backend

I dug into go recently and I'm really trying to get a grip of how casual Web Applications can benefit from concurrency. Let's take a blog for example. Every blog post has an author, and (in PHP) the template would typically look like:

```
<h1><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?> <small><?php echo $post->getAuthor()->getName(); ?></small></h1>
<?php echo $post->getContent(); ?>
```

The Controller really doesn't need to do a lot except fetch the blog post from the database and hydrate an Entity/Model. In my eyes, there is not much a concurrency pattern could do, is there?

Are there good examples for Backend Services being called concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a document style GET request to bring back the entire GET and then display the parts? As for updatess, I have seen REST API designers (like Espresso Logic) return in the response of a POST all the documents impacted. For example, if the POST results in a multi-table update the response should include all the document values and avoid another the GET.  Let the server handle the validation, optimistic locking, business logic, and multi-table insert/updated.  In your example, you could do a single POST with a nested document including all the parts of the blog entry and let the control handle the multi-table inserts and primary key propagation to the child tables (assuming SQL).